# c# непроходимая стена

Tags: c#

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы курсор не мог двигаться за пределы заданной области (допустим, пересечь лэйбл). Написал такой код:

```
 private void label6_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X-3,Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
```

Чтобы при попытке пересечь стену курсор смещался на несколько пикселей обратно. Однако это работает только при условии, что я веду курсор плавно, если резко провести через лейбл, то ничего не происходит. Подскажите, почему программа работает неправильно или же лучший способ реализации (чтобы курсор не мог преодалеть объект, а останавливался перед ним). Заранее спасибо.

Вариант из ответа, всё равно при резком движении программа не срабатывает:

```
 private void MoveCursor()
    {
        // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
        // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 5, Cursor.Position.Y);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
    }

    private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveCursor();
    }
```

Comment: Трек мыши - список (массив) координат которые "успела" зафиксировать ОС при движении мыши. Получите его - потом проанализируйте, построив прямые между точками трека по уравнению линии. Проверьте пересечение точек с лабел - если да -> репозиция + фиксация. Фиксацию вам показали. Задача нетривиальная - врядли её решение опубликуют вам со всеми тонкостями.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это происходит из-за того, что при "быстром, резком" движении курсора система не успевает пересчитывать координаты и условие просто не успевают выполниться.

Попробуйте задать курсору свойство [`Cursor.Clip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx):

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо за совет! Однако при резком движении всё равно ничего не просиходит..

Comment: @Алексей покажите, пожалуй, трек (след) вашей мыши, и уже отталкиваясь от этого поставьте корректно задачу. Например как отловить движение мыши если точки трека находятся за пределами области движения, т.е. нужна мышеловка. Конечно если трек мыши не пересекает область срабатывания mousemove - то ничего хорошего не будет. Скорее всего вам тогда нужно ставить хук на мышь, а вот стоит ли затраченое время цены задачи...  Если область ловли мыши - окно приложения - тогда хук не нужен - но тоже немного сложнее. Краевые задачи бывают заковыристыми.

Comment: Как и в большинстве задач я надеялся, что существует какое-либо простое и элегантное решение. Если его нет, то попробую просто изменить подход к задаче. Спасибо большое за такой развёрнутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

понизил скорость мыши до 1 при движении в окне.Таймером в program.cs и теперь с кодом автора(приведенным ниже) не выходит за стену :)

```
    private void label6_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X-3,Cursor.Position.Y);
    }
```